# SetAttributeFilter Issue

Tags: python, geometry, ogr

I am following the book "Geoprocessing with Python" and I have encountered an issue with my code:

```
from osgeo import ogr

shp_ds = ogr.Open('path/to/data')

volcano_lyr = shp_ds.GetLayer('us_volcanos_albers')

cities_lyr = shp_ds.GetLayer('cities_albers')
    
#How far is a particular city from a volcano?
volcano_lyr.SetAttributeFilter("NAME = 'Rainier'")
feat = volcano_lyr.GetNextFeature()
rainier = feat.geometry().Clone()

cities_lyr.SetAttributeFilter("NAME = 'Seattle'")
feat = cities_lyr.GetNextFeature()
seattle = feat.geometry().Clone()

#Distance function:
meters = round(rainier.Distance(seattle))
miles = meters / 1600
print('{} meters ({} miles)'.format(meters, miles))
```

I get this error:

```
  File "[redacted]", line 136, in <module>
    seattle = feat.geometry().Clone()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'geometry'
```

It opens perfectly fine in QGIS and the columns are named the same. Additionally, I managed to analyse how many cities there are in the city layer (redacted here), so this file should definitely have geometry.

Would anyone be able to assist?

Comment: That code, using the US [osgeopy-data](https://github.com/cgarrard/osgeopy-data) works fine. Your data must be different as I can only reproduce the error if I use a city name that is not actually in the cities layer, i.e. `cities_lyr.SetAttributeFilter("NAME = 'Does not exist'")`

Comment: The code does look fine but you need to add a trap for feat == None on both GetNextFeature() for robustness. Check that cities_albers has a field called NAME and that there is at least one record that has NAME = 'Seattle'. Attribute queries can be case sensitive if the underlying data source is case sensitive, shapefiles aren't but PostGIS is, check that the data source has proper case in its NAME field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments! Turns out my shapefile was corrupted. I downloaded the data from the link that user2856 provided me and it works now. Really appreciate it. I spent way too long on it. Should have thought of that..